# How can I wrap with <span> with JQuery an unknown word inside a ul list?

Tags: jquery, html-lists, html

I have this list

```
<ul>
  <li>Unknown word: Text here</li>
</ul>
```

How can I make it `<li><span>Unknown word</span>: Text here</li>` ?
I just want to begin the `<li>` with a `<span>` and put the `</span>` before the "**:**" character.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('li').html(function(i, h){
    var s = h.split(':');
    return '<span>' + s[0] + '</span>:' + s[1]
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CvB8J/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
var arr = $('#theli').text().split(':');
$('#theli').html( $('<span>'+arr[0]+'</span>') ).append(':'+arr[1]);
```

See working [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/DQqnp/).

Answer (score 1):

```
$("ul li").each(function() {
 var text = $(this).text().split(":")[0];
 var textNew = "<span>" + text + "</span>";
 $(this).html($(this).text().replace(text, textNew));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = $('li').text().split(':');
$('li').html("<span>" + a[0] + "</span>:" + a[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who prefer regex..

```
$('li').html($('li').text().replace(/^([^:]*)(.*)/ig, '<span>$1</span>$2'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ygE4C/1/